# Ubuntu 22 PXE Kickstart With Cobbler

Tags: boot, 22.04, pxe, kickstart, cobbler

I am trying to PXE kickstart Ubuntu 22 using Cobbler, but I am getting error

> /init: line 49: can't open /dev/sr0: No medium found

I believe when boot files are loaded, it's trying USB or CD drive and failing from there.
Steps taken:

- Extract Ubuntu 22 Server ISO File and copy the files and directories needed for PXE boot.
- Cobbler import

  ```
   sudo sudo cobbler import --path=/services/ubuntu22/ --name=xx-Ubuntu22_AMD64 --breed=ubuntu --kickstart="/var/lib/cobbler/kickstarts/ubuntu22_amd64--1.cfg
   sudo cobbler sync
  ```
- PXE Boot in VMware using Cobbler DHCP / TFTP

The errors I got:

[image: errors from console]

Comment: You need to supply a bit more info bud... Have you solved this already? If so, can you please post your solution. If not, - What Version of Cobbler are you using?
- Please post the content of /etc/cobbler/settings[.yaml]
- Please post the contents of /var/lib/cobbler/kickstarts/ubuntu22_amd64--1.cfg